# Ubuntu 18.04 - Login loop after hard reset

Tags: login

I was running a python jupyter notebook cell when the RAM memory went full. I hard reseted the computer.

After this, I could no longer login with my user.

It keeps on a login loop: after I enter my password, I can see my wallpaper and then it suddenly comes back to the login window.

I've already tried some workarounds available in the internet, such as verifying the .Xauthority and .ICEauthority files, removing the ~/.local folder, but no success.

My .xsession-errors file reads:

```
xrdb: Can't open display ''
xhost:  unable to open display ""
xhost:  unable to open display ""
```

It only happens with my specific user. I can normally login on the other ones.

Comment: I had a problem just like this after a hard reset - my drive had been corrupted, and I fixed it by booting a live USB, and running fsck from there.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'll try it as soon as I can

Comment: @Seiji, did that solution do the trick for you?

Comment: No. Actually I moved all the hidden files from my home folder and it happened to successfully login. Then, I moved back one by one until found the problematic one